# eclipse says to insert "EnumBody" to complete EnumDeclaration

Tags: java, eclipse, file

I wanted to create a method to write on files. But i got this error

```
 Syntax error, insert "EnumBody" to complete EnumDeclaration
```

Here is my code

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
public class ClassA throws IOException{
  public void writer(){
    PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter("Name.txt", "UTF-8");
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    writer.println("The first line");

    writer.close();
  }
}
```

and my main class is

```
public class Main {
public static void main(String[] args){
    ClassA test = new ClassA();
    test.writer();
  }
}
```

There is red line under class(in Writer class) and '{' after IOException.
What is the problem and if it can't be solved how to declare a method to write on File.

I am using eclipse on Windows10.

Comment: Classes don't throw exceptions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Classes don't throw exceptions, methods do.  Move `throws IOException` to the `writer()` method signature.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
public class ClassA {
  public void writer() throws IOException {
    PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter("Name.txt", "UTF-8");
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    writer.println("The first line");

    writer.close();
  }
}
```

Comment: It seems that there should be an an IOException on main method too. Am I right?

Comment: I would catch the IOException in the `Main` method rather than throw it out of `Main`.

Comment: You can throw exceptions from ```main``` just fine, they will be caught by the threads exception handler. (just like unchecked exceptions)

Answer (score 0):

Method main also must throws IOException

```
import java.io.IOException;

public class Main {

 public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    ClassA test = new ClassA();
    test.writer();
 }

}
```